How to Implement Waiting Mechanism in Golang for Goroutines to Retrieve Pages in a Pool Without Returning nil?
How can I implement waiting for a goroutine to receive a page in the context of a filled pull? Since nil should never be returned for Page if there's no error.
type Browse struct {
    b       *rod.Browser
    ctx     context.Context
    pool    []*Page
    launch  *Launch
    maxSize int
    mu      sync.Mutex
}



func (b *Browse) Page(proxy string, url string) (*Page, error) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    defer b.mu.Unlock()

    for i := range b.pool {
        if !b.pool[i].IsActive() {
            err := b.pool[i].SetUp(proxy)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            return b.pool[i], nil
        }
    }

    if len(b.pool) < b.maxSize {
        p := stealth.MustPage(b.b)

        page, err := NewPage(p, proxy, url)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        b.pool = append(b.pool, page)
        return page, nil
    }

    // TODO: not return nil
    return nil, nil
}


func (b *Browse) PutPage(page *Page) {
    err := page.CleanUp()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error cleaning up page", err)
    }
}

Using:
page, err := v.browse.Page(s.proxy, s.url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error getting page", err)
    return
}
defer v.browse.PutPage(page)

I attempted to implement a mechanism for retrieving resources from a pool in Go. I expected the goroutine to wait if the pool was full before returning nil, ensuring that nil is never returned unless there's an error. However, the current implementation does not handle this scenario as expected, potentially leading to nil returns.

Your current implementation does not handle the case where pool reached maxsize. Also, the algorithm runs with the mutex locked, so having multiple goroutines is meaningless. Consider using a chan *Page with a cap=maxSize instead of a slice pool.

Maybe you could make use of token channel and polling like following,
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Page struct {
}

func NewPage() (*Page, error) {
    return &Page{}, nil
}

func (p *Page) IsInactive() bool {
    return false
}

type Browse struct {
    ctx     context.Context
    working sync.Map
    tokens  chan int
    maxSize int
}

func NewBrowse(maxSize int) *Browse {
    b := &Browse{
        // ...
        ctx:    context.Background(),
        tokens: make(chan int, maxSize),
    }
    for i := 0; i < maxSize; i++ {
        b.tokens <- i
    }
    return b
}

func (b *Browse) checkInactivePage() *Page {
    p := new(Page)
    b.working.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
        if w, ok := value.(*Page); ok {
            if w.IsInactive() {
                p = w
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    })
    return p
}

func (b *Browse) Page(ctx context.Context, proxy string, url string) (*Page, error) {
    inactive := b.checkInactivePage()
    if inactive != nil {
        // Do something with inactive page and return
        return inactive, nil
    }
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-b.tokens:
            // p := stealth.MustPage(b.b)
            page, err := NewPage()
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            b.working.Store(t, page)
            return page, nil
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil, ctx.Err()
        default:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            inactive := b.checkInactivePage()
            if inactive != nil {
                // Do something with inactive page and return
                return inactive, nil
            }
        }
    }
}

